# Relation between belongsTo and hasMany in cakephp 3.4.9

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I need to save user and invoice data at the same time. When I am submitting the form, the user data is saving, but the invoice table isn't. When I print the request data, I get the following:

```
object(Cake\ORM\Entity) {

'u_firstname' => 'John',
'u_lastname' => 'den',
'u_email' => 'john@man.com',
'u_phone' => '123',
'password' => '123',
'membership_id' => (int) 1,
'Invoices' => [
    'inv_membership_name' => 'basic1',
    'inv_membership_cost' => '55',
    'inv_purchase_date' => '2017-07-11'
],
'id' => (int) 19,
'[new]' => false,
'[accessible]' => [
    '*' => true
],
'[dirty]' => [],
'[original]' => [],
'[virtual]' => [],
'[errors]' => [],
'[invalid]' => [],
'[repository]' => 'Users'
```

}

I am not able to save the `Invoice` part. I define **InvoicesTable.php**

```
 public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->setTable('invoices');
    $this->setDisplayField('id');
    $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

    $this->belongsTo('Users', [
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
}
```

and `UsersTable` like this:

```
$this->hasMany('Invoices', [
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
```

I use the following code to save data:

```
$user = $this->Users->newEntity();
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
      $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data(), [
            'associated' => [
                'Invoices' 
            ]
        ]);
    if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
       $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been saved.'));
   }else{
       $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
    }
 }
```

Please suggest what I'm missing. Or how I should debug.

Answer (score 0):

When you print request data `invoices` array should be something like this:

```
object(Cake\ORM\Entity) {
   'invoices' => [
        [0] => Array
             (
            ['inv_membership_name'] => 'basic1',
            ['inv_membership_cost'] => '55',
            ['inv_purchase_date'] => '2017-07-11'
        ),
        [1] => array('...') // if you have multiple records
 ],
```

For that change input name to something like this in your form:

```
invoices[]['inv_membership_name']
invoices[]['inv_membership_cost']
invoices[]['inv_purchase_date']
```

See here [Saving HasMany Associations in CakePhp3](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-hasmany-associations).

Comment: I modify my code and request data coming like this.
object(Cake\ORM\Entity) {

 'u_firstname' => 'John',
 'u_lastname' => 'den',
 'u_email' => 'john@mail.com',
 'u_phone' => '323232',
 'password' => '123',
 'membership_id' => (int) 2,
 'Invoices' => [
  (int) 0 => [
   'inv_membership_name' => 'basic 2',
   'inv_membership_cost' => '25',
   'inv_purchase_date' => '2017-07-12'
  ]
 ],
but still its not saving invoice data.

Comment: you need to have 'invoices' instead of 'Invoices'.

Comment: After changing to invoices it coming like this 
'u_firstname' => 'John',
 'u_lastname' => 'den',
 'u_email' => 'john@mail.com',
 'u_phone' => '323232',
 'password' => '123',
 'membership_id' => (int) 1,
 'invoices' => [
  (int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\Invoice) {

   'inv_membership_name' => 'basic1',
   'inv_membership_cost' => (float) 55,
   'inv_purchase_date' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenDate) {

    'time' => '2017-07-12T00:00:00+00:00',
    'timezone' => 'UTC',
    'fixedNowTime' => false
   
   },
but now neither user is saving nor invoice.

Comment: can you post your form ? looks like your data are still not formatted well. and how is your validation rules in InvoivesTable ?

Comment: This my validation rule in invoice
 $validator
            ->integer('id')
            ->allowEmpty('id', 'create');
 $validator
            ->requirePresence('inv_membership_name', 'create')
            ->notEmpty('inv_membership_name');
 $validator
            ->numeric('inv_membership_cost')
            ->requirePresence('inv_membership_cost', 'create')
            ->notEmpty('inv_membership_cost');
$validator
            ->date('inv_purchase_date')
            ->requirePresence('inv_purchase_date', 'create')
            ->notEmpty('inv_purchase_date');

Comment: this is my form
<input type="text" name="u_firstname" class="form-control" placeholder="First name*" id="u-firstname">
<input type="text" name="u_lastname" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name*" id="u-lastname">
<input type="text" name="u_email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email*" id="u-email">
<input type="hidden" name="invoices[0][inv_membership_name]" id="inv_membership_name" value="basic1">
<input type="hidden" name="invoices[0][inv_membership_cost]" id="inv_membership_cost" value="55">

Comment: everything looks good..may be there is something missing in your invoices table..!

Comment: Have you looked at `$user->errors()` after the save fails?

Answer (score 0):

You are close to the solution but you have the naming conventions wrong in the form. The correct name would be `invoices.0.inv_membership_name`
`invoices.1.inv_membership_name` etc. I included the creating inputs for associated data link from the cookbook.

`echo $this->Form->control('invoices.0.inv_membership_name');`

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-inputs-for-associated-data